# pypy в production

Tags: python

Сейчас все говорят о плюсах использования `pypy`, но никто не говорит о его минусах. Какие они ? И если он так хорош, то почему так мало людей выкладывают `pypy` - проекты в production ?

Comment: Очень мало бинарных библиотек, которые PyPy поддерживает.